# Loop through folders - copy data from files to main file

Tags: vba, loops, copy, append, directory

I want to do loop through folders and subfolders.
It works in my code. My next step is doing check - if specified cell in 4th column is not empty(in every file in subfolders), then copy values from files to my main file(for example ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet) - append.
In every try i have problems, now it is "Object variable or With block variables not set." But doing set makes new error. 
Can someone help?
Regards

```
Sub DoFolder()

Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
Dim FileName As String
Dim PathName As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim newbook As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim col As Range, coll As Range
Dim someRange As Range


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
queue.Add fso.GetFolder("Y:\MDM\__ZADANIA\LISTOWANIE\Archiwum\") 'obviously replace


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Nagłówki do nowego pliku z danymi
Set newbook = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
With newbook
    .Columns("A").Cells(1, 1) = "Subsystem"
    .Columns("B").Cells(1, 1) = "MGB"
    .Columns("C").Cells(1, 1) = "EAN Zakupowy"
    .Columns("D").Cells(1, 1) = "Liczba jednostek sprzedaży w kartonie"
    .Columns("E").Cells(1, 1) = "Ilość sztuk w jednostce sprzedaży"
    .Columns("F").Cells(1, 1) = "Nazwa pliku"
    .Columns("G").Cells(1, 1) = "Katalog pliku"
End With

'Fitowanie kolumn
With newbook.Columns("A:G")
    .AutoFit
End With


'zczytywanie ifnormacji z formatek po foldrach i dodawanie do istniejącego pliku
Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        queue.Add oSubfolder
    Next oSubfolder
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Set Wb = Nothing
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile)
        Wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
        For i = 15 To 515
            Set someRange = newbook.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not someRange Is Nothing Then
               lastRow = someRange.Row
            Else
                lastRow = 1
            End If
            If Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 4).Value
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 4).Value
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 30).Value
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 56).Value
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 14).Value
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 4).Value
                newbook.Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = Wb.Sheets("Dane_Dostawcy").Cells(i, 4).Value
            Else
                GoTo MyStatement
             End If
MyStatement:
         Next i
     Next oFile
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: which line is producing the error?

Comment: lastRow = newbook.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is producing an error because it cannot find anything, and you are asking for the `.Row` of that anything.

This is a way to go around it:

```
Dim someRange As Range
Set someRange = newbook.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not someRange Is Nothing Then
    lastRow = someRange.Row
Else
    lastRow = 1
End If
```

Thus it only gives the row value to `lastRow` in case that it has found something. Based on your business logic, if it does not find anything the row could be the first one.

---

Second Option for the error (thanks @QHarr) - you have to declare `dim lastRow as Long` and not as a range.